# Loop extracted cell(iloc) based on column variable into a list when reading multiple data

Tags: python, pandas

I want to loop based on newly created column name but i got this error at df1['mouse'].append(a.iloc[5,8]) : int object is not subscriptable.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfdata = []
for file in files:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file, sheetname='sheet1')
    dfdata.append(df1)

df1 = pd.concat(dfdata)
df1['mouse'] = np.empty((len(df1),0)).tolist()
df1['kb'] = np.empty((len(df1),0)).tolist()
df1['monitor'] = np.empty((len(df1),0)).tolist()

for a in df1:
    df1['mouse'].append(a.iloc[5,8])
    df1['kb'].append(a.iloc[6,8])
    df1['monitor'].append(a.iloc[7,8])
    b = {'Mouse':df1['mouse'],'Keyboard':df1['kb'],'Monitor':df1['monitor']}

dfAll = pd.DataFrame(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot comment to your question yet because I don't have enough reputation points.
Thus I write an answer.

Without an example with real data it's a bit difficult to understand your question.

However, I can see a few possible issues in your code:

If I'm correct, you first create 3 new columns, so that you have an empty list in every row like this:

```
   mouse  kb monitor
0    []  []      []
1    []  []      []
2    []  []      []
3    []  []      []
4    []  []      []
5    []  []      []
```

and you do it with this code:

```
df1['mouse'] = np.empty((len(df1),0)).tolist()
df1['kb'] = np.empty((len(df1),0)).tolist()
df1['monitor'] = np.empty((len(df1),0)).tolist()
```

Then I think you are trying to fill the new columns with this:

```
for a in df1:
    df1['mouse'].append(a.iloc[5,8])
    df1['kb'].append(a.iloc[6,8])
    df1['monitor'].append(a.iloc[7,8])
    b = {'Mouse':df1['mouse'],'Keyboard':df1['kb'],'Monitor':df1['monitor']}
```

One problem is that, when you call `for a in df1:`, you are iterating over the string names of the columns of `df1`. Then you call `.iloc`, but it can't work because `a` is a string. 
You should do something like this: `df1[a].iloc`.

However, you can't give 2 indices if you want to select a value in a column, because a column have only one dimension, so you should call `.iloc[i]` where i is the index of the column.

Also, when you try to add a value to `df1['mouse']` you are calling `.append` on all the column "mouse". You should also define the index of the column, e.g. `df1['mouse'][i]` where `i` is an integer.

However, since you concatenated your input dataframes without ignoring their original indices, this may be a problem. Hence you should try to concatenate them like this: `df1 = pd.concat(dfdata, ignore_index=True)`.  See here for further information: [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

I hope I helped clarifying a bit!